# SELECT statement with OR and AND succeeds when database isn't fully populated, fails when it is.

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with select statement.

My table is populated with data and I am using this query to get specific data from table:

```
SELECT * FROM company WHERE
                                    (
                                    paid = 'yes' AND
                                    country = '$country'
                                    )
                                    AND
                                    (
                                    categoryid1 = '$subCategory' OR
                                    categoryid2 = '$subCategory' OR
                                    categoryid3 = '$subCategory' OR
                                    categoryid4 = '$subCategory' OR
                                    categoryid5 = '$subCategory' OR
                                    categoryid6 = '$subCategory'
                                    )
                                    ORDER BY title
```

My problem is:
When I have populated all 6 categories columns with data it will not select anything from table. But if I delete data from 1 category it will select the right data.

Anyone can help please?

Thanks much

Comment: does it matter which category is empty? Also you don't need the parenthesis before the last AND.

Comment: Query looks ok, do you have any surrounding code that could be in error?

Comment: can you show some of the data points and which ones are causing the problems.

Comment: kasavbere: Yes it doesn't matter which is empty. I just need to match one of them.

Joachim: I get $country from mysql_escape_string($_GET['country']) but i am sure there is correct input, tested it. All other code just output what I got from query :(

Comment: Do you get the same result when you run from the console (replacing variables with an example case)?

Comment: kevingallagher
Tried it from phpmyadmin. I got correct result. So there has to be problem somewhere in code...

Comment: Seems the problem likely is in the setting of the $subCategory variable, but without the code it's hard to diagnose. Maybe called $subcategory in the code with a lowercase c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding additional opportunities for a series of OR clauses to match should never make your conditional flip from True to False -- **unless** it's trying to match NULL or "" (empty string). In that case having one blank column would cause it to always match, and having data in all the columns would cause it to always fail.

I'll bet that if you check your code, $subCategory isn't being properly set, and your ORs are all looking for the category "".

Comment: Thank you. This was the problem. I had wrong initialization of subCategory :(

Comment: Well, you did a nice job of noticing and describing the unusual behavior with the blank column. And I had a fun "aha!" moment figuring it out, so at least some good came of it. For catching problems like this, I often find that echoing out the query I'm sending is really helpful (one downside of moving to prepared queries is that you can't do this, but you can still print the text of the query as well as the array of parameters you're sending it).